# Call NetSuite native calculate shipping button by script?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am Using User event aftersubmit on Sales order to add/update line item. As soon as line item updated shipping cost should recalculate. I am using real time shipping method and cost.

Now If I change item manually, I need to click ‘calculate’ button under Shipping tab, which calculate and update shipping cost. But when I add/update line item using user event, it became ZERO.

Is there any way to calculate shipping cost by script? Is there any way to run **functionality of native ‘calculate’ shipping cost button by script**?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your case i.e User event, we need a dynamic record to do this, so load a dynamic Sales Order record, using id from the Standard record in User Event context:-

```
var drSalesOrder = record.load({type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: salesOrderId, isDynamic: true});
```

Then doing the following operations in this order(will calculate and set the shipping cost on the order):-

```
drSalesOrder.setValue({fieldId: 'shipcarrier', value: 'nonups'});
drSalesOrder.setValue({fieldId: 'shipmethod', value: SHIP_ITEMS.FedEx_Ground}); // your shipmethod id here
drSalesOrder.setValue({fieldId: 'shippingcostoverridden', value: true});
drSalesOrder.save({ignoreMandatoryFields: true, enableSourcing: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not natively. We do the calculation by overriding the page element on pageInit, and  adding other operations before running the native NS API call.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but on my case I cant get these answers to work (although its the same what is in SuiteAnswer), and I was stuck for some hours trying to retrigger the computation of shipping cost.

What I did is to call the `calculateRates()` Netsuite's function on `saveRecord` function in client script. I am lucky the client does not require this in the server. Although its not the correct way but its more okay than not working :)

`const saveRecord = (context) => { Shipping.calculateRates(); return true; }`

Hope this helps. Thank you!